# How to check monadic IO properties with tasty-quickcheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

How does one test a monadicIO property with [tasty-quickcheck](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2017-03-01/tasty-quickcheck-0.8.4/Test-Tasty-QuickCheck.html)? I tried the following, where the `testCase` is working as expected (which is coming from HUnit), but the `testProperty` (from QuickCheck) is not compiling.

```
import Test.Common
import Models.Client as Client
import Foundation
import Test.Foundation.Types ()
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic as QCM
import Opaleye
import Data.Pool as P

tests :: ConnectionPool -> TestTree
tests dbPool = testGroup "All tests"
  [
    testProperty "Client DB" $ testClientDB dbPool
  , testCase "Existing client.properties in production" $ withResource dbPool testExistingClientProperties
  ]

testExistingClientProperties :: Connection -> Assertion
testExistingClientProperties = undefined -- REDACTED    


testClientDB :: ConnectionPool -> Property
testClientDB dbPool = monadicIO $ do
  withResource dbPool $ \conn -> do
    (client :: Client) <- pick arbitrary
    client_ <- run $ insertModel conn client
    QCM.assert (client == client_)
```

Error:

```
testClientDB :: ConnectionPool -> Property
testClientDB dbPool = monadicIO $ do
  withResource dbPool $ \conn -> do
    (client :: BloatedClient) <- pick arbitrary
    client_ <- run $ insertModel conn client
    QCM.assert (client == client_)
```

Comment: Have you seen that Opaleye has a test suite that you could use for inspiration?  https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/tree/master/Test

Comment: @TomEllis you meant "inspiration" in what way? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong while writing DB tests using QC? Because I can seem to run `testClientDB` via `QC.quickCheck` directly. It's just that it isn't composing with tasty's `TestTree`

Comment: I mean you could use the same testing setup as Opaleye's QuickCheck test cases if you like.  It might be easier than trying to discover your own way.  I don't think you're doing anything fundamentally wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I got something to compile, but it isn't pretty. I'm still looking for an easier way to write DB-based Quickcheck properties with tasty, where the connection is being picked from a pool (so that tests can be run in parallel)

```
testClientDB :: ConnectionPool -> Property
testClientDB dbPool = monadicIO $ do
  (client :: Client) <- pick arbitrary
  client_ <- run $ withResource dbPool $ \conn -> insertModel conn client
  QCM.assert (client == client_)
```